# PIP install softlayer error

Tags: python, pip, installation, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am having following attached error as screen shot while installing  pip install softlayer for windows 7 Laptop.

Please see the attached screen shot.
[image]

Comment: Can you install other packages, like `flask` for example?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with the P programming language.  Please do not use the [tag:p] tag.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is a unknown issue (not reproducible, I'm using python 2.7.12), there is no any report about this:

- https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-python/issues

As Harald's suggestion you can test:

> 1. Installing another packages
> 2. Try with another python version

If the issue is still reproducible, try to provide more information about the pip and python versions that you have installed (`pip --version` and `python --version`). Also if you have another additional libraries installed (`pip list`), in order to discard that one of them is causing a conflict.